# How to Call IWebElement method from another class?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program in VS using C# with Selenium that inputs data into a textbox of a certain website. And I found this method online that waits until the element exists.

Tried calling the **WaitUntilElementExists** method from another class but it doesn't work. Don't know if I missed something. Appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks in advance!

```
public static void InputTextbox(IWebDriver wDriver, string sElement, string sValue, int iIndex)
    {
        //calling WaitUntilElementExists method
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(wDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Name("value")));

        //input text box
    }



public static class WaitForElement
{
    public static IWebElement WaitUntilElementExists(this IWebDriver wDriver, By elementLocator, int iTimeout)
    {
        try
        {
            if (iTimeout > 0)
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(wDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(iTimeout));
                return wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(elementLocator));
            }
            return wDriver.FindElement(elementLocator);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Element with locator: '" + elementLocator + "' was not found in current context page.");
            throw;
        }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Use `WaitUntilElementExists` as regular static method

```
IWebElement element = WaitForElement.WaitUntilElementExists(driver, By.Name("value"), 20);
```

Or use it as [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), call it using the `IWebDriver` instance

```
IWebElement element = driver.WaitUntilElementExists(By.Name("value"), 20);
```